# Adding image to canvas via class not working

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a template of images that the user clicks on and this must then add that image to the canvas. I can add it using ID and `document.getElementById`, but when I try and add it via `document.getElementsByClassName` I cant get it to work. Can someone suggest something?

**HTML**

```
<img style="cursor:pointer;width:90px;height:120px;" class="img" src="designs/01.png">
<img style="cursor:pointer;width:90px;height:120px;" class="img" src="designs/02.png">
<img style="cursor:pointer;width:90px;height:120px;" class="img" src="designs/03.png">
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('img').onclick = function() {
    var imgElement = $(this).attr("src");
    var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        angle: 0,
    });

    canvas.add(imgInstance);
}
```

Comment: how is `canvas` declared ?

Comment: Are you sure the canvas is initialized?

Comment: canvas = new fabric.Canvas('tcanvas')

Comment: I have various other functions that work under the canvas, text and adding an image from local pc etc, that all works correctly. This function is under the same canvas

Comment: minimal jsfiddle will be helpful to solve ur problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(".img").click(function(){
   var imgElement = $(this).attr("src");
   fabric.Image.fromURL(imgElement , function(img) {
     canvas.add(img);
     img.center();
   });
});
```

And to make sure your image url is retrieved in the click, add this line and check for console value

```
var imgElement = $(this).attr("src");
console.log(imgElement );
```

Comment: Thanks Madushak but it does not work, no image appears.